# Causing Rabbis Bitul Torah

Tags: torah-study, rabbis, wedding

Why is it not considered causing Bitul Torah if I invite Roshei Yeshivos to my wedding- let alone that not all will receive a recital of Berochos?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30840 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37765 and more tangentially http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18942.

Comment: This may be helpful (though I didn't inspect it properly and cannot vouch for it): http://ketertorah.org/class_material/Chesed/wedding/sources.pdf

Comment: As noted elsewhere, Rambam holds that there is no obligation to learn Torah every minute. He holds that the only "bittul Torah" is that described by dvar Hashem baza which refers to completely rejecting the study of Torah. I dont think that attending a wedding is included in this category.

Answer (score 5):

As was mentioned in the comments, we ignore the problem of בטול תורה because, as the gemara in [Kesubos 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.17a.11) says:

> תנו רבנן מבטלין תלמוד תורה...ולהכנסת כלה
>
> The Sages taught: One suspends the study of Torah...to attend the entry of a bride into the wedding canopy.